# Learnig NER using category list

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, named-entity-recognition, crf, crf++

In the template for training CRF++, how can I include a custom `dictionary.txt` file for listed companies, another for popular European foods, for eg, or just about any category.

Then provide a sample training data for each category whereby it learns how those specific named entites are used within a context for that category.
In this way, I as well as the system, can be sure it correctly understood how certain named entites are structured in a text, whether a tweet or a Pulitzer prize winning news article, instead of providing hundred megabytes of data.

This would be rather cool. Model would have a definite dictionary of known entites *(which does not need to be expanded)* and a statistical approach on how those known entites are structured in human text.

*PS - Just for clarity, not yearning for a regex ner. These are only cool if you got lots in the dictionary, lots of rule and lots of dulltime.*

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are talking about is Gazetteers list (dictionary.txt).

You would have to include corresponding feature for a word in training data and then specify it in template file.

For Example: Your list contains the entity: `Hershey's` 
and training data has a sentence: `I like Hershey's chocolates.`

So when you arrange the data in CoNLL Format (for CRF++), you can add a column (which shall have values 0 or 1 , indicating is the word is present in dictionary) which will have 0 value for all words, except Hershey's.
You also have to include this column as feature in template file.

To get a better understanding on Template File and NER training with CRF++, you can watch the below videos and comment your doubts :)

1) https://youtu.be/GJHeTvDkIaE

2) https://youtu.be/Ur5umC4BwN4

EDIT: (after viewing the OP's comment)

Sample Training Data with extra features: https://pastebin.com/fBgu8c67
I've added 3 features. The `IsCountry` feature value ( 1 or 0 ) can be obtained from a Gazetteers list of countries. The other 2 features can be computed offline. Note that Headers are added in file for reference only, should not be include in training data file.

Sample Template File for the above data : https://pastebin.com/LPvAGCVL

Note that, Test Data should also be in the same format as Train Data, with the same features / same no of columns.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43410468/2096740 - THe dataset and template works poorly with crf++. What other features and improvements in dataset would you suggest. This would make it abundantly clear the best way crf++ works. And in the same dataset, if I had to include gazetteers, could you give an example modification?

Comment: Could you share your test data as well,?

Comment: Not much, few headlines - https://gist.githubusercontent.com/arjunmenon/552619a8e536a08892e94082b606ee43/raw/8fba46cb714316b224ceb1029fe2d3c3961b45a4/test1.data

Comment: I am not thoroughly clear on the gazetteer part. If I am to include `1 or 0` in the training data if a entity is in the gazetteer, why should the test data also indicate that? It is possible an entirely new entity is given to the model which would not be in the gazetteer, nor it sounds feasible to run each entity first through the gazetteer, given the `1 or 0` label and then passed to the CRF? This would become more like a regex type validation. Nothing statistical

Comment: My reply to your comment is very long so I am unable to comment it.
I have written my reply here : https://pastebin.com/L2kHRX51

Comment: I tried the reformatted data you pasted. It still does not predict any of the labels. I guess that those youtube videos are yours.  Would you make one covering these aspects of CRF++? Some hints about all case insensitive data training would be cool to know.